# Деловая жилка

Tags: фразеология

Когда о человеке говорят, что у него есть способность к чему-то, то употребляют выражение, например, "деловая жилка". А почему именно жилка?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ЖИЛКА — 1. То же, что жила. Кровь заиграла по жилкам. 2. Способность, природная склонность к какой-н. творческой деятельности (перевод фр. veine).

В русском языке слова "нервы, жилки, фибры "  передавали значение жизненной силы и, соответственно, содержали информацию о всем существе человека. Например:Ликовала душа, каждая жилка играла в теле. Каждая жилка дрожала у него внутри при встрече с домом.

Поэтому слово жилка используется, когда говорят о способностях человека. Каждая жилка - это весь человек, а конкретная жилка - это часть его натуры.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Это просто в ней артистическая жилка билась, как во всех нас.

Валентина Ивановна однажды объяснила ему, что у него есть творческая жилка.

У вас есть жилка торговца.